# Как разбить массив на 2 колонки, если в массиве есть пропуски?

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Здравствуйте!

Есть следующий код:

```
$array = array(Маша, Даша, Саша, Паша, Миша, Вова, Савва, Слава);
$names = explode(",", $array);
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
 if (trim($value)!="")  {

       $Names_list .= '<span><img src="'.$key.'.gif">'.$value."</span>";

}
}
```

Вопрос, как разбить на две колонки, учитывая, что не все имена могут быть в массиве, например:

```
$array = array(Маша, , Саша, Паша, , Вова, Савва, );
```

И тогда конструкция вида:

```
if ($key % 2) {

} else {

}
```

уже отработает неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$c =0;//считаем выводы
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
 if (trim($value)!="")  {
    if ($c==2){                //если  вывели 2 элемента - переносим строку
         $Names_list.= "<br />";
         $c=0;                 //Обнуляем счетчик
    }
       if ($c == 0){           //1 столбец
        $Names_list .= '<span><img src="'.$key.'.gif">'.$value."</span>";
       }else{                  //2 столбец
        $Names_list .= '<span><img src="'.$key.'.gif">'.$value."</span>";
       }
      $c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать вместо explode функцию [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php):

```
$string = 'Маша, , Саша, Паша, , Вова, Савва, ';
$array = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($array);
```

Получаем:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => string(8) "Маша"
  [1] => string(8) "Саша"
  [2] => string(8) "Паша"
  [3] => string(8) "Вова"
  [4] => string(10) "Савва"
}
```

Comment: Если вы заметили, то в коде имена картинок задаются ключом:

<img src="'.$key.'.gif">

при вашем подходе Саша будет с фотографией Маши)